# Car Class Object Oriented Programming Python

Tags: python, oop

I am defining a class called 'car' I am comparing it to a document that runs a series of tests on my class. However, I am getting wrong answers in the Drive Method, and I am not sure why.

Here's my code. The Drive method is supposed to take the car and move it a specified amount of miles as a parameter. If the car can achieve all the miles without running out of fuel, then the car makes the trip and outputs the miles while also incrementing the odometer. If it can't make the trip and still have fuel in the tank, then it drives for however long until the `fuelLevel` is 0.

If there's any invalid parameters given, then the car isn't supposed to drive. Each time the class gets to 'Test 9' in the Car Tester program, it breaks. So all of the subsequent ones break too. Below I have posted my code first, and then the code to test it out.

Can you help me? I appreciate it

```
#Define the class 


class Car(object): 

    def __init__(self,fuelEfficiency=0,fuelCapacity=0,fuelLevel=0,odometer=0):
        self.setCar(fuelEfficiency,fuelCapacity,fuelLevel,odometer)

    def setFuelEfficiency(self,newFuelEfficiency):
        self.setCar(fuelEfficiency = newFuelEfficiency)

    def setFuelCapacity(self,newFuelCapacity):
        self.setCar(fuelCapactity = newFuelCapacity)

    def setFuelLevel(self,newFuelLevel):
        self.setCar(fuelLevel = newFuelLevel)

    def setOdometer(self,newOdometer):
        self.setCar(odometer = newOdometer)

    def setCar(self,fuelEfficiency = None,fuelCapacity = None,fuelLevel = None,odometer = None):
        if fuelEfficiency == None:
            fuelEfficiency = self.getFuelEfficiency

        if fuelCapacity == None:
            fuelCapacity = self.getFuelCapacity

        if fuelLevel == None:
            fuelLevel = self.getFuelLevel

        if odometer == None:
            odometer = self.getOdometer

        self.fuelEfficiency = fuelEfficiency
        self.fuelCapacity = fuelCapacity
        self.fuelLevel = fuelLevel
        self.odometer = odometer

    def drive(self,miles):
        if miles < 0:
            return ("The car is not driven")

        one_gallon = miles / self.fuelEfficiency

        if one_gallon < self.fuelLevel:
            print("The car drove {} miles".format(miles))
        elif self.fuelLevel == 0:
            print("The car drove 0 miles")
        #else:
            #newMiles = milesDriven * miles
            #print("The car drove {} miles".format(newMiles))

        self.fuelLevel -= one_gallon
        self.odometer += miles   


    def getCar(self):
        #Returns a tuple that has (FE,FC,FL,OD)
        return (self.fuelEfficiency,self.fuelCapacity,self.fuelLevel,self.odometer)        


    def addFuel(self,num):
        if type(num) == str:
            return self.fuelLevel
        if num < 0:
            print("Sorry, you need to enter a postive number.")
            return self.fuelLevel

        if (self.fuelLevel + num) > self.fuelCapacity:
            return self.getFuelLevel
        if (self.fuelLevel + num) == self.fuelCapacity:
            self.fuelLevel += num
            return self.getFuelLevel
        if (self.fuelLevel + num) < self.fuelCapacity:
            self.fuelLevel += num
            return self.getFuelLevel

    def getFuelEfficiency(self):
        return self.getCar()[0]

    def getFuelCapacity(self):
        return self.getCar()[1]

    def getFuelLevel(self):
        return self.getCar()[2]

    def getOdometer(self):
        return self.getCar()[3]

    def tripRange(self):
        numOfMiles = self.fuelEfficiency * self.fuelLevel
        return numOfMiles

    def __str__(self):
        FE = self.getFuelEfficiency()
        FC = self.getFuelCapacity()
        FL = self.getFuelLevel()
        OD = self.getOdometer()

        string = '{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(FE,FC,FL,OD)
        return string
```

And here's the tester program that goes hand in hand with testing if the class works properly. If everything is fixed, the output will be "No Errors Found"

```
from car import *
def main():
    c = Car(25, 15)
    checkNum(c.tripRange(), 0, 'Test 1')    

    expected = (25, 15, 0, 0)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 2')

    c.addFuel(-1)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 3')

    c.addFuel(1000)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 4')

    c.addFuel('doctor')
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 5')

    c.addFuel(0)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 6')

    c.addFuel(15)
    expected = (25, 15, 15, 0)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 7')

    c.drive(50)
    expected = (25, 15, 13, 50)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 8')

    c.drive(100000)
    expected = (25, 15, 0, 375)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 9')

    c.drive(5)
    expected = (25, 15, 0, 375)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 10')

    c.addFuel(10)
    expected = (25, 15, 10, 375)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 11')

    c.drive(-1)
    expected = (25, 15, 10, 375)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 12')

    c.drive(0)
    expected = (25, 15, 10, 375)
    checkCar(c, expected, 'Test 13')

    checkNum(c.tripRange(), 250, 'Test 14')

    if not errorsFound:
        print('No Errors Found')


def checkCar(car, expected, message):
    global errorsFound
    mpg, cap, level, odo = expected
    if car.getFuelEfficiency() != mpg:
        errorsFound = True
        print(message + ': Error efficiency. Expected ' + str(mpg))
        print('\tCar:', car)
    if car.getFuelCapacity() != cap:
        errorsFound = True
        print(message + ': Error capacity. Expected ' + str(cap))
        print('\tCar:', car)
    if car.getFuelLevel() != level:
        errorsFound = True
        print(message + ': Error level. Expected ' + str(level))
        print('\tCar:', car)
    if car.getOdometer() != odo:
        errorsFound = True
        print(message + ': Error odometer. Expected ' + str(odo))
        print('\tCar:', car)

def checkNum(value, expected, message):
    global errorsFound
    if value != expected:
        errorsFound = True
        print(message + ': Error value. Expected {}. Got {}'.format(expected, value))

errorsFound = False
main()
```

Comment: I don't know what textbook or class you're learning Python from, but it is bad. There's probably two or three times the amount of code that there should be in a proper Python class.

Comment: Totally agree with TH.  Python is not Java.  Nor is it C.  You can start out by giving default values of 0 to most of your variables rather than None.  Then, while it is nice you are thinking of unitests already (really), I suggest you take a look at the Python Unit test module.  This is a good intro:  http://www.diveintopython.net/unit_testing/.  setCar, as defined and used, smells quite a bit off as well.  You could use *properties* if you really wanted to or you could just assigned the values directly.

Comment: Of the 15 methods in `Car`, only five are actually worth anything. The rest are just cheap magicians tossing things around and waving their wands, trying to fool you with sleight-of-hand.

Comment: It's sad, because it's at the Unverisity of Iowa -.- Trust me, I know this stuff sucks.

Comment: I suggest discussing this issue with someone at your university who has the authority to make some positive changes. Remember, you are the customer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in drive method that why the program is crashing

```
test above 9 car status:
fueleffiency = 25
fuel = 13
```

in test 9 c.drive(100000)
in drive method there is no check if one_gallon > self.fuellevel and that's 
exactly occurs in test 9 one_gallon = 100000/25 = 4000 which is greater than
fuel level after test 8
try  this for drive

```
def drive(self,miles):
    if miles < 0:
        return ("The car is not driven")
    one_gallon = miles / self.fuelEfficiency

    if one_gallon < self.fuelLevel:
        print("The car drove {} miles".format(miles))
    elif self.fuelLevel == 0:
        print("The car drove 0 miles")
    elif one_gallon > self.fuelLevel:
        print("car cannot drive") #or any overflow condition
    self.fuelLevel -= one_gallon
    self.odometer += miles
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `drive()` method that literally implements what you said you wanted:

> The Drive method is supposed to take the car and move it a specified
>   amount of miles as a parameter. If the car can achieve all the miles
>   without running out of fuel, then the car makes the trip and outputs
>   the miles while also incrementing the odometer. If it can't make the
>   trip and still have fuel in the tank, then it drives for however long
>   until the fuelLevel is 0.

```
    def drive(self, miles):
        if miles < 0:
            return  # The car is not driven

        trip_gallons = miles / self.fuelEfficiency

        if trip_gallons <= self.fuelLevel:
            self.odometer += miles
            print("The car drove {} miles".format(miles))
            self.fuelLevel -= trip_gallons
        else:
            miles_possible = self.fuelLevel * self.fuelEfficiency
            self.odometer += miles_possible
            print("The car drove {} miles".format(miles_possible))
            self.fuelLevel = 0  # Out of gas
```

You might want to consider adding some code the then of your `checkCar()` that resets the car to the expected values if `errorsFound`. That way, one test failing would mess up all the ones that follow.